# ModelChoiceField lists tuples instead of simple values

Tags: django, forms, modelchoicefield

I have a django form with a ModelChoiceField input and it lists the result as tuples instead of simple values.

I have no clue on how to do it.

```
DJANGO
class PayThis(forms.Form):
   amount = forms.FloatField(required=False)
   cost2  = forms.FloatField(required=False)
   year = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False,queryset=AnAgricol.objects.values_list('anul').all())

 HTML
 <option value="(2019,)">(2019,)</option>
```

I expect to get this: < option value="2019">2019< /option >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ModelChoiceField` deals, like the name suggests, with model objects. You thus can not use `values_list` here.

Your `Form` thus should define something like:

```
class PayThis(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.FloatField(required=False)
    cost2  = forms.FloatField(required=False)
    year = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=AnAgricol.objects.all())
```

You can override the `__str__` to return a string representation of the year, like:

```
AnAgricol(models.Model):
    anul = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.anul)
```

If the year however is not something to represent `AnAgricol`, then you could use a [**`ChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield), like:

```
class PayThis(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.FloatField(required=False)
    cost2 = forms.FloatField(required=False)
    year = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['year'].choices = [
            (yr, yr) for yr
            in AnAgricol.objects.values_list('anul', flat=True).distinct()
        ]
```